# What causes my div to be hidden?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I am writing a page, consisting of a fixed-size  with a lot of content. This is why the  has a scrollbar (normal behaviour). Right after the scrollbar I want to create an element, which will allow the  to change its width (make the  resizable). Unfortunately, this element ("resizer") is not showing. Why is it hidden?
Here is the link with example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZYBHN/.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
   #wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 200;
   }
   #resizer 
   {
    border:1px solid red;
    cursor: e-resize;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
   } 
   #content
   {
     width:100%; 
     height:100%;
     overflow:auto;
     position:relative;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" > 
<div id="content"> 
.....Lots of text here....
</div>
<div id="resizer"></div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dunno about you, but I can see it and the mouse cursor/pointer changes too. Probably you can notice it on a [wider window](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYBHN/embedded/result/).

Comment: The `overflow: hidden` on `#wrapper` is causing it to be hidden.. is that what you meant?  Or some other reason?

Comment: to Dream Eater: You are right - but instead of 10 pixel width <div> only a red border is showing. When you hover your mouse over this border, you see cursor changing its view, which is normal behavior, but I just need that "resizer" to be wider!

Comment: cimmanon, you're 100% right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your `#resizer` element inside the `#wrapper`, which has `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`. You've positioned your `#resizer` absolutely, relative to the `#wrapper`, -10 pixels from the right (IE the right of it is outside the wrapper element). The `overflow: hidden` of `#wrapper` is keeping this from displaying outside its boundaries.

Comment: You are correct, as cimmanon was also correct 8 minutes before. Shame that such an obvious thing didn't come to my own mind...

Comment: I glossed over that comment, or I would have had him post it as an answer. My bad.